# Using arguments.length in Object-prototype

Tags: javascript, arguments, prototype

I have a person class that has a sub-class of User and Admin and User will create user instances...
Now validating my addPerson() properties by checking the arguments.length will not work.

if statement won't get executed even though i can log arguments.length

```
var Person = function(name, email) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;

  this.addPerson = function(name, email) {
    var paraLength = arguments.length;
    console.log(paraLength) //logs 2
    if(paraLength < 2 || > 2) {
      return "Input must be just name and email"; //does nothing
    }else{
    //do other things
    }
}

const User = function(name, email) {
  Person.call(this, name, email);
  this.addPerson(name, email); //adding user on execution
};

User.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

//Pointing User constructor to itself so it can override properties
User.prototype.constructor = User;
var user1 = new User("user1", "email@gmail", "this error", "not just ignored")
```

I'd like to terminate on return statement if the parameter passed in are less or more than two. 
Note: I intend using object prototype

Comment: Your code should not even run. `if(paraLength < 2 || > 2) {` results in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >`

Comment: "Only ES5" <- I don't think `const` and `let` are ES5 :P

Comment: I meant to say using Object prototype. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what `User.addPerson()` is supposed to do, but to answer your main question…

If you want to catch too many (or too few) parameters passed to `new User()` in the `addPerson()` function, you could pass on the `arguments` rather than  just the name and email. You can do that with:

```
this.addPerson.apply(this, arguments);
```

to make `addPerson` see all the arguments passed into `User()`

```js
var Person = function(name, email) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;

  this.addPerson = function(name, email) {
    var paraLength = arguments.length;
    console.log(paraLength) //logs 2
    if(paraLength < 2 || paraLength > 2) {
      console.log( "Input must be just name and email"); //does nothing
    }else{
    //do other things
    }
}
}

const User = function(name, email) {
  Person.call(this, name, email);
  this.addPerson.apply(this, arguments); //adding user on execution
};

User.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

var user1 = new User("user1", "email@gmail", "this error", "not just ignored")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors - in your `if` statement, you're missing the `paraLength` on the second comparison (should be `|| paraLength > 2`). You also haven't closed off your original `Person` function. And since you're not doing anything with the `return` value of `addPerson`, nothing happens - use `return console.log` to return *and* log to the console:

```js
const Person = function(name, email) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;

  this.addPerson = function(name, email) {
    let paraLength = arguments.length;
    console.log(paraLength) //logs 2
    if (paraLength < 2 || paraLength > 2) {
      return console.log("Input must be just name and email"); //does nothing
    } else {
      console.log("2 arguments!");
    }
  }
}

const User = function(name, email) {
  Person.call(this, name, email);
  this.addPerson(name, email); //adding user on execution
};

User.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
User.prototype.constructor = User;

//All tests are below this line

let user1 = new User("user1", "email@gmail", "this error", "not just ignored");
user1.addPerson("one", "two", "three");
user1.addPerson("one");
```

Comment: ```let user1 = new User("user1", "email@gmail", "this error", "not just ignored");``` This first instance get run without error but the parameter are more than two. I fire the function when instances are created